# Adding gms google service to android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I first try under module build gradle as following.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I notice each time the gradle sync will take too long to load almost 20 minutes. Then after googling I found some solution to do this in build.gradle for the project itself it can now sync all is fine but all my google map related codes are showing red. But I have remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

For example its showing this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
             .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

cannot resolve symbol etc.

Even this it say cannot resolve symbol android?

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your app Gradle file

```
compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1
```

Comment: i tried is the same back to the original problem it take a long time to do the gradle sync build. actually i dont understand why the gradle build need to run each time isnt those library like com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1 is already been added once in the begining?

Comment: how stop from the sync from keep repeating the same process each time I just change my codes few lines

Comment: Clear cache from Android studio and restart. It happen sometimes

Comment: I read there is android cache and gradle cache which one to clear?

Comment: Open Android studio, Go to file menu and Choose Invalid Cache / Restart